# Mean, and standard deviation

Tags: java

I am working on this assignment for class and I cant seem to see where I am going wrong. I put the same input as the example from my professor but I have a different output. with inputs 1,2,3,4.5,5.6,6,7,8,9,10 the mean is 5.61, and standard deviation is 2.99794373974304. but I am getting the mean 5.61 which is correct, but a standard deviation of 2.9963144027287916. Not sure where I am going wrong. any ideas? not looking for someone to do this for me. I just need to know where I am going wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //User Input 1-10
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputA = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputB = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputC = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputD = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputE = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputF = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputG = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputH = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputI = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    double inputJ = input.nextDouble();

    //Formula for Mean
    double mean = (inputA + inputB + inputC + inputD + inputE + inputF + inputG + inputH + inputI + inputJ) / 10;

    //Formula for standard deviation
    //Subtract each input by the mean
    double m1 = (inputA - mean);
    double m2 = (inputB - mean);
    double m3 = (inputC - mean);
    double m4 = (inputD - mean);
    double m5 = (inputE - mean);
    double m6 = (inputF - mean);
    double m7 = (inputG - mean);
    double m8 = (inputH - mean);
    double m9 = (inputI - mean);
    double m10 = (inputJ - mean);

    //Square each m variable
    double v1 = (Math.pow(m1, 2));
    double v2 = (Math.pow(m2, 2));
    double v3 = (Math.pow(m3, 2));
    double v4 = (Math.pow(m4, 2));
    double v5 = (Math.pow(m5, 2));
    double v6 = (Math.pow(m6, 2));
    double v7 = (Math.pow(m7, 2));
    double v8 = (Math.pow(m8, 2));
    double v9 = (Math.pow(m9, 2));
    double v10 = (Math.pow(m10, 2));

    //Add all the sums squared sums together
    double var = (v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6 + v7 + v8 + v9 + v10);


    //divide by the number of variables to get Variance
    double var1 = (var / 10);
    double var2 = (var % 10);
    double var3 = (var1 + var2);

    //Standard deviation is the square root of the Variance
    double dev = (Math.sqrt(var3));

    //Mean and Deviation print
    System.out.println("The mean is " + mean);
    System.out.println("the deviation is: " + dev);
}
```

Revised my coding. but I am still off. can anyone help me get a more accurate answer? im still stumped!

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {



    double[] arrayM = new double[10];
    double[] arrayV = new double[10];

    double sum = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < arrayM.length ; index ++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double in = input.nextDouble();
        arrayM[index] = in;
        sum += in;    
    }
      //final mean and variant
        double mean = sum/arrayM.length;
        double vari = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < arrayM.length ; index ++) {
        double var=((index+1)-mean)^2;
        arrayV[index] = var;
        vari += var;
    }
        double variant = vari/arrayM.length;
     //final deviation   

     double devi= Math.sqrt(variant);




    System.out.print("The mean is: "+mean);
    System.out.print("The standard deviation is: "+devi);

 }
```

}

so where it says mean within the double var=((index+1)-mean)^2 won't work. how can I write it so it's - mean

FINAL EDIT: I figured it out. here is the final code.

```
    public class TESTPROJECT {

  /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here



 //Arrays
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] arrayM = new double[10];
        double[] arrayV = new double[10];


    //Sum 
    double sum = 0;


    //Sum array
    for (int index = 0; index < arrayM.length ; index ++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        double in = input.nextDouble();
        arrayM[index] = (in);
        sum += in;    
    }

    //Mean
    double mean = sum/arrayM.length;

    for (int index = 0; index < arrayM.length ; index ++) {
        double var = arrayM[index] - mean;
        arrayV[index] = var;
    }

    //Variant Loop
    double sqre = 0; 

    for(int index = 0; index < arrayV.length; index++) {
        double sqr = Math.pow(arrayV[index],2);
        sqre += sqr;
    }

    //Deviation cal
    double variant = sqre/arrayM.length;

     //final deviation   

     double devi= Math.sqrt(variant);



     //ouput
      System.out.println("The mean is: "+mean);
      System.out.println("The standard deviation is: "+devi);

 }
 }
```

Comment: Have you heard of loops?

Comment: Don't use Math.pow(x,2). Use x*x instead

Comment: Do you actually know the definition of variance?

Comment: I have not taken stat so I do not know the literal definition.  I will try what you suggested. I have heard of loops, but for some reason I started going with this and it made sense to me. I will revise it with loops.

Comment: @MarkKeen BigDecimal doesn't support square root and the error is in the third decimal place. Do you really this this is floating point representation error?

Comment: Where does `(var % 10)` come into it? What happens if you remove this?

Comment: The issue seems to be in the var/10 + var%10 step. I don't understand why it's there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the solution (But your implementation is not very convenient).
Refer to the definition you've been given of variance and deviation.
This should have been done way before starting to code. If you don't find definition, try here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

You are wrong somewhere here:

```
//divide by the number of variables to get Variance
double var1 = (var / 10);
double var2 = (var % 10); // why ?
double var3 = (var1 + var2); // and why ??
```

By the way, using an array and loops might be of help, here is a snippet :

```
    double[] valuesArray = new double[] {1.0,2,3,4.5,5.6,6,7,8,9,10};

    double mean = 0;
    double variance = 0;
    double deviation = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < valuesArray.length ; index ++) {
        mean += valuesArray[index];

        System.out.println("value "+ index + " is : "+valuesArray[index]);
    }

    System.out.println("Sum : "+mean);

    // divide sum by number of values
    mean = mean / ((double) valuesArray.length);

    System.out.println("Mean : "+mean);
```

Comment: I am trying this now. I will let you know the outcome. The bottom line is I need to make loops. also the top part. I was assuming that there was a remainder that was not accounted for. and when I did that it got closer to the actual answer.

Comment: I have kind of figured it out. I am just struggling with pulling values from the array and having it calculate each value in a loop, then storing it in a second array to pull from later.

Comment: You can do a very similar loop for deviations squared mean : create a new array of same length and put in each row the corresponding squared deviation to mean ( see formulas). Here You can use this loop to prepare the deviations mean (In fact you are just computing another mean, so the code sample I given needs a bit of adaptation for the deviation purpose). 1 new array 2 loop to fill it with individual deviation 3 use loop to sum those deviations 4 once loop finished, divide the sum of deviations 5 compute std deviation 6 voilà

Comment: By the way, this is a 2 step process. You can't compute everything in a single loop.

Comment: Ho and I just noticed that my use of indexes is a bit messy : start loop from index 0 and to "length", and write at "index" (instead of start loop at 1 to "lenght+1" and write at "index-1"...)